# Reinstate System Menu after reverting to Gnome Classic?

Tags: panel, menu, gnome-classic

How do I get the system menu back on the top panel after reverting to Gnome Classic on 11.10 like suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic/63315#63315)  to [How to revert to Gnome Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Comment: Aren't you among "the people that want the classic menus"?

Comment: Yes, mikee. But the new classic menu, what they call the classic menu of gnome-classic, is no longer the classic classic menu. It doesn't have the System menu with the and Administration menus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, the system menu cannot be brought back. You can get the shortcuts by enabling the "Other" menu. See http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/ubuntu-11-10-upgrade-missing-your-system-menu-preferences-administration-launchers/ .

Answer (score 2):

I never found any native method to do so either.. 
So instead i installed cairo (cairo-dock) and when installed i find the same old classic menu by clicking the icon with the ubuntu logo.
And this contains the System and Administration menus as well..

hoping this help you !