# How to get back the system menu for Gnome fallback mode

Tags: menu, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reinstate System Menu after reverting to Gnome Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66293/reinstate-system-menu-after-reverting-to-gnome-classic)

Is there any chance to get back the system menu for gnomes fallback panel? I really can't get warm neither with unity nor with Gnome-Shell. So I am using the Gnome fallback mode. And I am wandering if there is any hope to get the system menu back. In Ubuntu 11.10 it is really hard to find some system configurations using Unity as well as Gnome-Shell or fallback mode. The system-preferences window is really poor and I am missing many preferences there. It is also unacceptable that this window is not resizeable.