# I cannot revert completely to gnome-classic menus in 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, menu, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reinstate System Menu after reverting to Gnome Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66293/reinstate-system-menu-after-reverting-to-gnome-classic)

After installing the packages to be able to login to the gnome-classic desktop I only have the menus: Applications and Places in the gnome-panel, but there is no System menu with the preferences and Administration menus.

Where are the System and the Administration menus, can I get them back in gnome-classic 12.04?